# Global solution to the ODE if $f$ is linear

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I was reading an ODE textbook, and there was a part where it was explained under which condition IVP:

$$\dot{x}=f(x); \; x(t_0)=x_0$$

with $f:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^n}$ has local, global and unique solutions, most of the things were rather clear but there was one question regarding the effect of the linearity where I got confused. So the question is:

If we assume that $f$ linear, is there for all $t\in\mathbb{R}; \; x_0\in\mathbb{R^n}$ a global solution to the IVP?

I couldn´t find any theorem that would imply it but I might be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear IVP $$\dot{x} = A x;\ x(t_0) = x_0$$
has an explicit global solution $$x =  \exp((t-t_0) A)\; x_0 $$
where $\exp$ is the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential).

Comment: Since it is explicit we can state that the solution is automatically unique in this case?

Comment: Uniqueness follows from the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem.  Explicit does not necessarily imply unique, e.g. there might be one explicit solution and lots of non-explicit ones.